# QML WebView clear cached data or expose QWebView to QML

Tags: qt, webview, qml, qwebview, qt5.4

I'm building a Qt/QML application using: Qt 5.4/QtQuick 2.0/QtWebKit 3.0 for a Mac Desktop Application, and I was looking for a way to clear QML Webview cached data but till now nothing is working with me, I tried to use

```
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0
```

and used

```
experimental.preferences.privateBrowsingEnabled: true
experimental.preferences.offlineWebApplicationCacheEnabled: false
```

and I tried to clear the cached data of the NetworkAccessManager from C++ but nothing happened, Any help here would be appreciated

I tried to use QWebView and expose it to QML but I wasn't able to find a way to do this

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but you might try [providing your own QNetworkAccessManager to QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlnetworkaccessmanagerfactory.html) and clearing its cache.

Comment: I tried it but didn't solve the problem, Thanks

Comment: As far as I've understood, `NetworkAccessManager` is not (no more?) used to serve web-related stuff to the `WebView`... `WebView` should have its own mechanism to fetch data from the web and we might interact with them for disabling cache... However I've already tried to use _experimental_ methods (as in your code) but it does not work... Have you finally found a working solution for that? If so, could you share it with us?

Comment: Till now i didn't find anything, but I am still trying. If i reached for anything i will make sure to update

Comment: @MohamedElkassas: thanks for your update... here are my two cents: in my particular case (in which the content to be shown by the `WebView` was served by the means of a custom web server), I *temporarily* workaround-ed the problem including the `Cache-Control: no-cache` in HTTP response headers... this way the webkit underlying `WebView` obeys the directive and do not cache the corresponding content... but of course, you cannot do that if you haven't the control  on the web server which hosts the content that you want to publish to `WebView`...